# How to generate pairwise combinations of elements of 2 lists in Python

Tags: python

I’m trying to come up with a Python script to find all the pairwise combinations of the elements of two lists (regardless of their relative number of elements). For example, if ***A = ["a", "b", "c"]*** and ***B = [1, 2]***, the possible pair combinations taking 1 element from B, then 2 elements from B, and so on, against all the elements of A are (without repetitions):

```
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c')]
```

If ***A = ["a", "b", "c"]*** and ***B = [1, 2, 3]***, then the first 43 combinations using 1 element of B, then 2 elements from B, and so on against all the elements of A should be:

```
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'a')
(3, 'b')
(3, 'c')
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
[(2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(2, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
[(2, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
[(2, 'b'), (3, 'a')]
[(2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
[(2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
    :          :         :
    :          :         :
```

This is what I tried using code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-get-all-unique-combinations-of-two-lists/),

```
# import itertools package
from itertools import product, combinations

# initilize lists
A = ["a", "b", "c"]
B = [1, 2, 3]

# create empty list to store the combinations
unique_combinations = []
all_combinations    = []

all_combos = list(combinations(B, 1))

for j in range(len(all_combos)):
    # Extract Combination Mapping in two lists
    # using zip() + product()
    unique_combinations = list(list(zip(A, element))
                               for element in product(all_combos[j], repeat = len(A)))

    # Reverse the order of the tuples in the list
    for k in range(len(unique_combinations[0])):
        unique_action = [tuple(reversed(unique_combinations[0][k]))]

        all_combinations = all_combinations + unique_action

    # printing unique_combination list
    # print(unique_combinations)
    # print(f"There are {len(unique_combinations)} unique combinations\n")

for i in range(1, len(A)):
    all_combos = list(combinations(A, i))

    for j in range(len(all_combos)):
        # Extract Combination Mapping in two lists
        # using zip() + product()
        unique_combinations = list(list(zip(B, element))
                                   for element in product(all_combos[j], repeat = i+1))

        all_combinations = all_combinations + unique_combinations

        # printing unique_combination list
        print(unique_combinations)
        print(f"There are {len(unique_combinations)} unique combinations\n")

# printing unique_combination list
for i in range(len(all_combinations)): print(all_combinations[i])
print(f"\nThere is a total of {len(all_combinations)} unique combinations\n")
```

...but this is what I get,

```
(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'a')
(3, 'b')
(3, 'c')
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
```

It is close but not quite there. What am I doing wrong? How can we fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you sometimes get different counts in a result. Do you want a power set of the product?

Comment: I'm not that good at Python. Probably bad coding in my part. I'm following the script from the link  I included with some modifications.

Comment: So the correct answer is in the link? (Although we discourage links here, except official online documentation. You should copy the code into the question.) Is your problem python or math?

Comment: The link points at the code I borrowed. The problem is Python. What am I dong wrong in the Python script and how to fix it to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read your code, but I found a solution: For each size, get the product of A with *size* repeats, get the combinations of B of *size*, and then get their product and zip.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

for size in range(1, len(B)+1):
    a = product(A, repeat=size)
    b = combinations(B, r=size)
    for x, y in product(b, a):
        print(list(zip(x, y)))
```

Output for `B = [1, 2]`:

```
[(1, 'a')]
[(1, 'b')]
[(1, 'c')]
[(2, 'a')]
[(2, 'b')]
[(2, 'c')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'a')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'b')]
[(1, 'c'), (2, 'c')]
```

The output for `B = [1, 2, 3]` is the same as yours.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: Bonus round! How can I store the results as they are shown on the screen into a list?

Comment: @ixombi Haha, bonus round :) Create a list at the top level like `result = []` and store by replacing `print` with `result.append`.

Comment: Gee, I swear I tried that and didn't work with some error about not able to append itertools objects but it is working now. Thanks. Oh I see what I did wrong before, I called that "results" list "a" and that conflicted with a = product(A, repeat=size) .